# What are the differences between "Open Commerce API", "Demandware Order Management" and "Demandware API"

Tags: web-services, demandware

I'm wondering what are the differences between "Open Commerce API", "Demandware Order Management" and "Demandware API". Also I'd like to know how to get order information by using one of those APIs. Thanks a lot!

https://documentation.demandware.com/DOC1/index.jsp

Comment: More direct link https://documentation.demandware.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FOCAPI%2F17.1%2Fusage%2FOpenCommerceAPI.html

Answer (score 14):

**The Open Commerce API**, or more commonly **OCAPI** is a RESTful API that consists of three component APIs (as of v16.3):

- Shop API (Provides access to Demandware storefront functionality)
- Data API (Provides access to Demandware application configuration and integration functionality on a per object basis)
- Meta API (Provides access to a formal description of the resources and documents available in the Open Commerce API)

---

**Demandware Order Management** is Business Manager module named Orders (under Merchant Tools) that you can find, update, export or track orders.

---

**Demandware API** is actually what you see in that documentation page. It can be found in Eclipse (Help > Help Contents > Demandware API) as well.

---

If you are going to use DWAPI, it's really easy:

```
function getOrder(orderNo) {
  var OrderMgr = require('dw/order/OrderMgr');

  return new Order(OrderMgr.getOrder(orderNo));
}
```

Or, you can use OCAPI, it's also easy but it requires some kind of authentication first.

**[Get order](https://documentation.demandware.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/16.2/shop/Resources/Orders.html#id1963696827__id1089966539)**

Gets information for an order.

*URL*: `GET` https://hostname:port/dw/shop/v16_2/orders/{order_no}

*Formats*: json, xml

*Authentication*: OAuthOrJWT - Requests with an OAuth token or Customer JWT token are supported.

*Response Document*: Order

---

So, please explain where do you want to use your order details.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a separate product called Demandware Order Center, which has its own separate set of API classes in the Demandware Script API.

The way you have asked your question is way too broad.

EDIT: If you provide some background as to what problem you are trying to solve, we may be able to identify which API you should look at.

Comment: To be fair, they don't know what any of it means so they don't now how to be more specific. ;)

Comment: Hi there, Steve :)